# C++ - manipulating objects in a STL vector?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, stl, vector

I have structure like this:

```
struct Rz3DContourNode {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  float nx;
  float ny;
  float nz;
};
```

And I store elements in a STL vector as follows :

```
 std::vector < Rz3DContourNode >  nodes;
```

Now I want to change the nx,ny compoent of the nodes in the vector.I tried as follows:

```
*(&nodes[i].nx)=newNXValue;
*(&nodes[i].ny)=newNYValue;
*(&nodes[i].nz)=newNZValue;
```

This did not work.Is it because nodes[i] returns a copy of the object?

Is there any solution for this expect using pointers ?

I cannot use pointer (Rz3DContourNode*) , because I am using this vector in OpenGL as

```
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(Rz3DContourNode), &nodes[0].nx);
```

**EDIT - I am sorry.I actually keep a QList and get the std::vector everytime.That was the reason**

```
std::vector<Rz3DContourNode> nodeVector = nodes.toVector().toStdVector();
```

Comment: `nodes[i]` does not return a copy of the object, can you post some failing code? `*(&nodes[i].nx)=newNXValue;` could/should be simplified to `nodes[i].nx = newNXValue;`.

Comment: thanks, i was getting copy of the vector everytime.that was the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on my compiler....
Taking the address of the instance and then dereferencing it is the same as not doing it all. 
So you don't need it. So replace this

```
*(&nodes[i].nx)=newNXValue;
```

with

```
nodes[i].nx = newNXValue;
```

Here is the code sample I tried:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

struct Rz3DContourNode {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  float nx;
  float ny;
  float nz;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector < Rz3DContourNode >  nodes;
    float newNXValue = 4545.4f;
    float newNYValue = 453.0f;
    float newNZValue = 34.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Rz3DContourNode node = {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
        nodes.push_back(node);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    {
        nodes[i].nx = newNXValue;
        nodes[i].ny = newNYValue;
        nodes[i].nz = newNZValue;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry,i was doing something terribly wrong.I was getting a copy of the vector each time .(from QList )

Comment: Sometimes when you been at it all day, you just can't see through your own problems until you ask someone for help. Then the answer suddenly becomes clear as you verbalize the problem to someone else. If you like the answer than, vote it up.

Answer (score 11):

Why bother with pointers? The `[]` operator returns references to stored objects, so you can just do

```
nodes[i].nx = newNXValue;
nodes[i].ny = newNYValue;
nodes[i].nz = newNZValue;
```